# Check if first or second element in list are same data type.Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am beginner in Prolog.I have my custom types bird,fish,animal. So the problem is I want to pass function like firstLast([owl,chicken,cat,eagle]) and get result true because first and last are same data type. For another example:

```
firstLast([dog,owl,shark,eagle,cat]).
> true

firstLast([shark,dog,owl,mouse]).
> false
```

This is my base data:

```
bird(eagle).
bird(chicken).

animal(cat).
animal(mouse).
animal(dog).

fish(shark).
fish(wheal).
fish(goldfish).

isSameType(X,Y):-
   (  bird(X),bird(Y)
   ;  animal(X),animal(Y)
   ;  fish(X),fish(Y)
   ).
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, using [last/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=last/2):

```
firstLast([X|Tail]):-
  last(Tail, Y),
  isSameType(X,Y).
```